# Configuring dnsmasq to filter A or AAAA queries

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, ipv4, dnsmasq

Can I configure dnsmasq to respond to either ipv4(A) or ipv6(AAAA) queries **only**?

I am using dnsmasq to forward queries from an internal subnet to a WAN connection.
Unfortunately, sometimes I will only have an ipv6 connection on the WAN interface, but a client will send both A and AAAA queries and then choose to use the ipv4 address from the responses. The reverse can also happen at any time.

I should mention that I don't use dnsmasq for dhcp, so changing the internal subnet to ipv6 is not really an option.

I've looked through the dnsmasq configuration options, but nothing seems to fit my requirements.
I suppose I can filter the requests or the responses with the firewall, but I'm afraid that would trigger a lot of retries.

Comment: There are some unofficial patches. But you would have to compile dnsmasq yourself.

Answer (score 2):

version 2.87:

Add `--filter-A` and `--filter-AAAA` options, to remove IPv4 or IPv6    addresses from DNS answers.